# C# WPF math expressions on variables in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, variables, math

I digged out the internet in order to find a solution, and didn't found any clear solution and none of them working.

I'm looking for a specific solution, but if someone here have better solution it will be great..

In general, I'm trying to make controls that based on the Width and Height of the monitor. 
- The easy way is put values that matches with my monitor and change them from CodeBehind.

Here's how it going:
 - Create two variables in XAML (let's say the type is Double)
 - Create third variables also in XAML. His value will be the difference of the 
 other two variables (in absolute) 
 - Create 3 control, the width of those controls is the value of the variables

```
<Window xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib >
 <sys:Double x:Key="size1">290</sys:Double>
 <sys:Double x:Key="size2">450</sys:Double>
 <sys:Double x:Key="size3"> Maybe something here? </sys:Double>

 <StackPanel>
  <Button Name="Button1" Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource size3}}" 
          Height="50" />
 </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I'm new in WPF, I do know C# pretty well but XAML is new for me (few months).
Basically I want to know if its possible to use undefined variables, such as 10% of the screen width.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Converter](https://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to achieve that.

```
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value / 10;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

in Xaml

```
 <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:WidthConverter x:Key="WidthConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Name="Button1"
            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}"
            Height="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: How I could put this value of my 'Screen Height' into variable in XAML?
Some thing like this:
    <sys:Type x:Key="screenHeight"> Add Something Here </sys:Type>